# Android XML element is not allowed

Tags: android, android-layout

I have the following XML layout which basically gives me rounded corners and I use it on EditText's.  Why does Android inspector say that the `element solid is not allowed here` and also `element corners is not allowed here.`

It works fine, should I just leave it?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>    
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
    <corners
        android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
        android:topRightRadius="5dp" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That XML file should be located in `res/drawable`. It might be located in `res/layout`, which is an incorrect location.

Comment: so simple, yet I could not figure out why it was saying that.  Works perfect.  Thank you for your wisdom :)  Will mark as correct as soon as it lets me.