# how to remove this warning - "Element SwitchPreferenceCompat is not allowed here"?

Tags: android, xml

In an Android project inside res/xml/ file name pref_visualizer.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <SwitchPreferenceCompat
        android:defaultValue="@bool/pref_show_bass_default"
        android:key="@string/pref_show_bass_key"
        android:summaryOff="@string/pref_show_false"
        android:summaryOn="@string/pref_show_true"
        android:title="@string/pref_show_bass_label" />
    <SwitchPreferenceCompat
        android:key="@string/pref_show_mid_key"
        android:title="@string/pref_show_mid_label"
        android:summaryOff="@string/pref_show_false"
        android:summaryOn="@string/pref_show_true"
        android:defaultValue="@bool/pref_show_bass_default" />
    <SwitchPreferenceCompat
        android:key="@string/pref_show_treble_key"
        android:title="@string/pref_show_treble_label"
        android:summaryOff="@string/pref_show_false"
        android:summaryOn="@string/pref_show_true"
        android:defaultValue="@bool/pref_show_bass_default" />

</PreferenceScreen>
```

The SwitchPreferenceCompat text is highlighted and says it cant be allowed here.How to fix this warning. The app runs without any problem. But still I would like to know How to fix this issue.

Comment: Maybe a [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38131254/7461132) problem.

Comment: I tried using that method but it didnt help. I checked and I found that my directories are quite correct.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Try to replace `PreferenceScreen` with `android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceScreen` in the root tag of your preference XML file (the pref_visualizer.xml in this case).

Comment: Do we need to change the inheriting class for the preference activity as well i.e something like
MyPreferenceActivity extends android.support.v7.PreferenceActivity ?

Answer (score 4):

The "SwitchPreferenceCompat" tag belongs to the com.android.support:preference-v7:28.0.0 library.
so you need to match the libraries of the parent "PreferenceScreen" tag and the "SwitchPreference" tag (@f0rrest suggested to update the parent tag to v7). however the instructions and recommendation in the android developer site (developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings) is to use the AndroidX Preference Library. 
therefore i suggest to migrate the project to AndroidX and use "androidx.preference.PreferenceScreen" for the parent tag.

Comment: Could you add some more explanations?

Comment: It would be better to put these explanations inside the question by editing it.

Comment: @Paradox I deleted the comment and changed the original answer to include the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Your PreferenceScreen's layout cannot be in res/layout/ they have to be in res/xml/

Answer (score 1):

As a supplement to f0rrest's answer for the newer versions, you could also replace `PreferenceScreen` with `androidx.preference.PreferenceScreen` which will also work.

Comment: This worked for me, I wonder why this works? Do you know what library `PreferenceScreen` uses by default when specifying `androidx.preference:preference:1.1.x` in your gradle build settings? Or perhaps this is a different dependency that I need to upgrade instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use `SwitchPreference` instead of `SwitchPreferenceCompat`.

Comment: I tried it now the app has started to crash with the error :: Error inflating class (not found)SwitchPreference

Comment: Make sure you have added `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'` in gradle dependencies. Change the version according to your Build Tools Version

Answer (score 0):

Use the full path to the class in the xml to avoid the issue:

```
<com.example.CustomSwitchPreference..
```