# Layout Editor "Design" button missing for v7 PreferenceScreen

Tags: android, android-studio, android-support-library, support-preference

Normally when editing a `preferences.xml` file in Android Studio, one can switch to the layout editor by clicking on the "Design" button at the lower left of the screen:

[image: design button]

After clicking the button, the layout editor is shown for this xml file:

[image]

But when I change the `PreferenceScreen` to `android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceScreen` (as e.g. suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32070186/how-to-use-the-v7-v14-preference-support-library/32919694#32919694)), the button disappears (it is necessary to re-open the xml file to see this effect):

[image]

1. Is this behavior normal or is this just my Android Studio installation (v3.1.1 on Windows) - i.e. is the layout editor not yet implemented for v7 preference xml files?
2. Is it somehow possible to open the layout editor when using v7 preferences anyway? Does a good workaround exist?
3. It seems that not explicitly declaring the `android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceScreen` in the xml file does work nevertheless with v7 preferences, so somehow the `android.preference.PreferenceScreen` gets converted to a `android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceScreen` behind the scenes. Is there any downside when using v7 preferences and not explicitly declaring `android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceScreen` in the xml file (so one can still use the layout editor)? What is the difference, if any (other than possible [compiler warnings regarding not allowed xml-elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44843043/how-to-remove-this-warning-element-switchpreferencecompat-is-not-allowed-here))?